# How to create single value as "% time a value is positive"

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have a metric in my app which at different times throughout the day pushes a non-negative integer (0,1,2,3,4,5...) to my influxdb database.

I can't work out the InfluxQL or Flux query to display a rolling figure for 'the % of time the value is > 0', over the last say 24h (configurable).

This should definitely be possible but everything I try doesn't provide an error message I can iterate on.